# How do I know the exact exception type?

Tags: c++, exception, mfc, exception-specification

We use `CDynamicAccessor` which inherits from [`CAccessorBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/data/oledb/crowset-class?view=msvc-160#movenext). The function `MoveNext` would throw

`HRESULT MoveNext() throw()`

but without telling what exception type it is. How do I know it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, [`throw()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec) means the function is declared not to throw any exceptions.

Note that it's deprecated (and removed in C++20); we can use [`noexcept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) (or `noexcept(true)`) since C++11.

Comment: This is what tripped me up. Thanks to StoryTeller for clarifying.

Comment: Oh my ... But it actually throwed. There supposed to be several corrupted entries, when executed MoveNext, it crashed. I'll dig further.

Comment: @Zhang About the behavior when the function throws exception not listed in exception specification, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec#Explanation).